# Database design for kids chore schema

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm wondering about best practise to keep a database as tidy as possible. The database is postgresql accessed by express.js/node. It is for a kids chores app that I'm working on and it has the following schema:

```
CHILDREN
    id
    name
    points
    rate
    created_at
    updated_at
    user_id

TASKS
    id
    description
    value
    days (boolean array - eg. [0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    periods (boolean array - eg. [0,0])
    created_at
    updated_at
    user_id

FINISHED TASKS
    id
    task_id
    child_id
    completed (boolean)
    created_at
    updated_at
    period (boolean)
    day (int (0-6))
```

For every individual finished task a row is created in the database. With only 400 children doing chores in there, there are already around 800 rows being added each day to the `FINISHED TASKS` table.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a  more efficient way of storing `FINISHED TASKS` either for a full day per child or similar?
2. With scale I'm going to end up with potentially tens of thousands of rows per day - is this  acceptable for an app like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a child table related to a task table through an intermediate bridge table is the common way of doing this.  My experience with large hospital applications is that once tables start to have millions of rows and performance is degrading, the applications typically archive the "finished tasks" into a separate archive table.  You would maybe end up with two tables, one called 'active tasks' that contains tasks where 'completed' is false and once the task is finished, the row is moved into the archived 'finished tasks' table.

Depending on how much effort you want to put into future proofing the application, this could be done now to prevent having to revisit this.